# Does $\int (\ln x)^{f(x)}dx$ have a closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

> Prove whether there exists a nonconstant function $f(x)$ such that $\displaystyle\int (\ln x)^{f(x)}dx$ has a closed form (i.e. it can be written using function composition, basic arithmetic operations, exponentiation operators, logarithmic operations, etc.). For instance, $\displaystyle\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ does not have a closed form.

I know that if I find one counterexample, I'll be able to disprove this statement. However, I am having trouble finding one. I know that $(\ln x)^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)\ln (\ln x)}$

Comment: And yet...it turns out to be easy.

Comment: ok. thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hmmm. Funny that you should have added the remark about $e^{f(x) \ln \ln x}$ *after* my answer, and removed your earlier thoughts.

Comment: @JohnHughes I genuinely already knew that, but I wasn’t sure if it would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln \ln x}$. Then 
$$
(\ln x) ^ {f(x)} = \exp(f(x) \ln \ln x) = \exp (\frac{1}{\ln \ln x} \ln \ln x) = e.
$$
which is nicely integrable. If you'd rather it was nonconstant, you can pick 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln \ln x}
$$
to make the integrand be $e^x$.

Comment: More generally, choose your favorite function $\phi(x)$ with closed form integral, and then let $f(x)$ be the solution of $$(\ln x)^{f(x)} = \phi(x)$$.

Comment: Yes...that's kinda what I was getting at with my second comment.

Comment: @GEdgar, my favorite function is $\phi(x)=-1$ for all $x$ (greater than $1$ if you like, to avoid problems in the meaning of $(\ln x)^{f(x)}$). What is the value of $f(e)$?